# Let $x,y$ be nonzero vectors and $u$, $v$ be their unit vectors. Lower-bound $\|u-v\|$ as an increasing function of $\|x-y\|$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, spheres, convex-geometry

Let $x$ and $y$ are nonzero vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, and $\hat{x} := x/\|x\|$, $\hat{y}:=y/\|y\|$ be corresponding unit vectors. One can easily show that

$$
\|\hat{x}-\hat{y}\| \le \frac{\|x-y\|}{\min(\|x\|,\|y\|)}.\tag{1}
$$

Indeed, w.l.og, suppose $\|x\| \le \|y\|$ and let $\alpha := \|y\|/\|x\| \ge 1$. Then, one computes
$$
\|x-y\| = \|x\|\|\hat{x}-\alpha \hat{y}\| \ge \|x\|\|\hat{x}-\hat{y}\|,
$$
where we've used the fact that if $u$ and $v$ are unit vectors and $\alpha \ge 1$, then $\|u-\alpha v\| \ge \|u-v\|$.

> **Question.** Can we get an **lower-bound** for $\|\hat{x}-\hat{y}\|$ in as an increasing function of $\|x-y\|$ (and perhaps some dependence on $\|x\|$, and $\|y\|$) ?

Comment: You provided an upper bound for $\|\hat x - \hat y\|$ in terms of $\|x - y\|$.  Did you mean to ask if there is an upper bound of $\|x - y\|$ in terms of $\|\hat x - \hat y\|$?

Comment: Or maybe you mean lower-bound in your question instead of upper bound?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Indeed i meant **lower-bound**. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing notation, let $u=\hat x$ and $v\hat y$ be unit vectors, and let $\alpha=\|x\|$ and $\beta=\|y\|$, so that $x=\alpha u$ and $y=\beta v$. Then
\begin{align*}
\|x-y\|^2 &= \|\alpha u-\beta v\|^2 = \alpha^2+\beta^2-2\alpha\beta(u\cdot v) \\
\|\hat x-\hat y\|^2 &= \|u-v\|^2 = 2-2(u\cdot v),
\end{align*}
and these two equations can be solved *exactly* to yield
$$
\|\hat x-\hat y\| = \sqrt{\frac{\|x-y\|^2-(\alpha-\beta)^2}{\alpha\beta}} = \sqrt{\frac{\|x-y\|^2-(\|x\|-\|y\|)^2}{\|x\|\cdot\|y\|}},
$$
which is indeed an increasing function of $\|x-y\|$ with dependence on $\|x\|$ and $\|y\|$. (Note that it quickly implies the upper bound given in the OP as well.)

Comment: Thanks. For fixed $0 < r \le R < \infty$, this immediately implies the nontrivial bound $\|\hat{x}-\hat{y}\| \ge \|x-y\|/\sqrt{Rr} + 1/ R - 1/r$, valid for all $x,y$ in the annulus with inner radius $r$ and outer radius $R$.